# How to generate dynamic error messages for JSON validation? (express-json-validator-middleware)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using JSON validation (express-json-validator-middleware) to validate request body. Lets assume I have colors field which holds array of strings. Now I am validating this field like so,

```
colors: {
  type: "array",
  items: {
    type: "string",
  },
  minItems: 1,
  maxItems: 6,
  uniqueItems: true,
  errorMessage: {
    type: "Colors should be an array",
    uniqueItems: "Colors should have unique items",
    maxItems: "Colors can not have more color than 6",
  },
},
```

Here in errorMessage I have to add messages manually to send every kind of error message so is there any way to reduce this code because I have too many fields like colors.

One way to give common error message for that field like for colors field I can add "Please enter valid colors", But I want to give exact error like "Array length should be 6" etc.

So I there any sort way to achieve it? Or Should I have to do all stuff manually?